# Stop R from overwriting graphics files

Tags: r, graphics

I am using R in batch mode from an iPad, and place the graphic files within ~/Dropbox, and view them there. When I run successive sessions of R, it overwrites the graphics files the previous run produces, even when I use

```
png(filename="Rplot%03d.png")
```

Is it possible to get R to continue incrementing the file name? For example, if I have `Rplot001.png` and `Rplot005.png` I would like the next file to go into `Rplot006.png`.

I know it would be possible to create a random prefix for the `png()` call using `paste()`, but I'd like to name them using the particular project I am working on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the most recent file, and increment from there. Something like:

### Serial Runs

```
projectPng <- function(projectName, dir, ...) {
  # get a list of existing plots for the project
  plots <- list.files(path=dir, pattern=paste0(projectName, "*.png"))
  # pull out numeric component of the plot files
  nums <- as.numeric(gsub(paste("Rplots", ".png", sep="|"), "", plots))
  last <- max(nums)
  # Create a new file name with an incremented counter.
  newFile <- paste0(projectName, sprintf("%03d", last + 1), ".png")
  # now call png
  png(file.path(dir, newFile), ...)
}
```

Now `projectPng` will open a new device with the next incremented number for the project:

```
# If Rplots005.png exists, will open Rplots006.png
projectPng("Rplots", "~/Dropbox")
```

### Multiple Parallel runs

Alternatively, if you are running multiple runs in parallel, you can store a global counter to minimise conflicts from each independent run when opening a new device:

```
projectPng <- function(projectName, dir, ...) {
  # Get the most recently opened device number as stored by `projectPng`
  counterFile <- file.path(dir, paste0(projectName, "_png_counter.txt")
  new <- tryCatch({
    last <- scan(file=counterFile, what=integer())
    cat(last + 1, "\n", file=counterFile)
    return(last + 1)
  }, error = function(e) {
    # If we're unable to open the counter file, assume no plots exist yet
    cat(1, "\n", file=counterFile)
    return(1)
  })
  # Create a new file name with an incremented counter.
  newFile <- paste0(projectName, sprintf("%03d", new), ".png")
  # now call png
  png(file.path(dir, newFile), ...)
}
```

**HOWEVER: this is not guaranteed to be safe:** If two R sessions call `projectPng` at the same time, there is a chance they will both obtain the same number from the `counterFile`, before the other has had a chance to increment the counter.

Comment: But when you do `png(filename="Rplot%03d.png")` you can call multiple `plot`s before `dev.off()` and they will all get a different number. With this method (if i'm reading it correctly) will return a single file name with no `%d`, so you can only call `plot` at most once before calling `dev.off()`. It looks like the "magic" `%03d` is passed off to the C-code with no way to specify a starting offset in the standard `png` function.

Comment: My understanding of the OP's question is that they are calling it from multiple R sessions. Otherwise you could just keep a global counter somewhere. The `%03d` just formats the number with multiple 0s before it (i.e. "006" instead of "6").

Comment: But R accepts "Rplot%03d.png" as a valid file name (in fact it's the default) and it auto increments the number for you. You have no control over that number that gets passed to `sprintf` or whatever to make it an actual file name. There is a big difference between using `Rplot%03d.png` and using `Rplot001.png`. The biggest difference is you will have to call `projectPng/dev.off` multiple times where you only have to call `png/dev.off` once.

Comment: You could do something like this: `png(filename=sprintf("Rplot_%s_%s.png", format(Sys.time(), '%d%m%Y_%H_%M'), '%03d'))`

Comment: @MrFlick I'm not sure I understand, but clearly I've misunderstood the question...

Comment: @ScottRitchie Or maybe I misunderstood it.

Comment: I actually can't get `png()` on its own to increment: The default `"Rplot%03d.png"` will create "Rplot001.png", but subsequent calls don't do anything (they aren't even overwriting "Rplot001.png").